# difference T Get<T>(int id) and T Get(int id)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

Can anyone tell me the difference between

```
public T Get<T>(int id)
```

and

```
public T Get(int id)
```

Comment: <T> indicates a generic type parameter which is defined at runtime.  This type is either specified during class instantiation (your second line would need to have had T defined during object creation) or when the method is called (your first line of code).

Comment: @davenewza: Your comment is correct both cases and actually is generic for ant generics. Something like "What does T mean here?" or "What is generics?" ;)

Answer (score 7):

Compare:

```
class First
{
    public T Get<T>(int id) // T is declared in the method scope
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
class Second<T>
{
    public T Get(int id) // T is declared in the class scope
    {
    }
}
```

Also there is a 3rd scenario:

```
class Third<U>
{
    public T Get<T>(int id) // T is declared in the method scope when class scope has another generic argument declared
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, and let me add that the confusion between these two cases is what leads to questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740978/type-parameter-t-has-the-same-name-as-the-type-parameter-from-outer-type

Comment: Don't forget the case where there is a type called `T` (don't do that!)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that you use the first type of declaration if this is when T hasn't been defined before. ie.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public T Get<T>(int id);
}
```

And the second when T has already been defined at the class level. ie.

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T Get(int id);
}
```

In this case you can also use the first type of declaration - this is effectively shorthand. There is no difference in the effect.

**Edit** In fact, the second declaration only requires that T be in scope, another example would be a nested class as in...

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
  public class NestedClass
  {
    public T Get(int i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0x6a29h6%28v=vs.80%29) before you can use them in code.