# Inner generic type same as outer - compiler warning

Tags: c#, generics, warnings, inner-classes

So I have a tree class:

```
public class Tree<T> : IEnumerable where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private Node<T> root = null;

    ...

    private class Node<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        private Node<T> left, right;
        ...
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I get the compiler warning: `Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'Tree<T>'`  Well, of course it's the same name, they should be the same type.  (In fact, since the `Node` class is private and thus can never be accessed outside of the `Tree` class, they are *guaranteed* to be the same type.  Is this compiler warning just BS which I can safely ignore?  Or is there some good reason why I should give the inner class a different generic name (other than just to make the warning go away)?

(I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740978/type-parameter-t-has-the-same-name-as-the-type-parameter-from-outer-type), which is about the warning itself, but this is clearly a different scenario.  The types are guaranteed to be the same, as `Node`'s are only created and accessed within the context of `Tree`, so there's no chance of confusion.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're misunderstanding nested type parameters.

The compiler is warning you about constructed types like `Tree<int>.Node<string>`.  Such types  will make your life *miserable*.  (I speak from personal experience)

If you want to use the outer `T` in `Node`, you shouldn't make `Node` generic.

In general, there are very few reasons to nest one generic type within a different one.

Comment: It'd be impossible to construct such a type, though, since `Node` is private.  (Okay, I suppose `Tree` could construct one internally, but it doesn't, so no worries.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Why wouldn't any of the omitted `...` construct a `Node`?

Comment: @hvd Yes, what I meant was it _could_ construct a `Node` _with a different type_, but it doesn't.  It only creates `Node<T>`'s.  If I were to do something as loony as `Tree<int>.Node<string>`, I'd expect errors or at least warnings, but that doesn't happen ever.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: But it could happen, and the compiler warns you that it might happen.  (before it's too late, so to speak)

Answer (score 4):

What you want is probably:

```
public class Tree<T> : IEnumerable where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private Node root = null;

    ...

    private class Node: IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private Node left, right;
        ...
    }
}
```

If you want the inner class to have the same T, you dont need to redefine it again.