# Inner class generic type same as outer type

Tags: c#, generics

I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154974/inner-generic-type-same-as-outer-compiler-warning) that *almost* answers my question, but I still don't fully understand.

Trying to write a Tree data structure, I did this:

```
public class Tree<T>
{
    public TreeNode<T> root;
    ...

    public class TreeNode<T>
    {
        List<TreeNode<T>> children;
        T data;
        public T Data { get { return data; } }

        public TreeNode<T>(T data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

And, anyone who's worked with C# generics apparently knows that I got this compiler warning: `Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'Tree<T>'`

My intent was to create an inner class that would be forced to use the same type as the outer class, but I now understand that adding a type parameter actually allows the inner class to be more flexible.  But, in my case, I want subclasses of `Tree<T>` to be able to use `TreeNode`, for example, like this:

```
public class IntTree : Tree<int>
{
    ...
    private static IntTree fromNode(TreeNode<int> node)
    {
        IntTree t = new IntTree();
        t.root = node;
        return t;
    }
}
```

(That method allows the subclass to implement `ToString()` recursively)

So my question is, if I take out the parameterization, like this:

```
public class Tree<T>
{
    public TreeNode root;
    ...

    public class TreeNode
    {
        List<TreeNode> children;
        T data;
        public T Data { get { return data; } }

        public TreeNode(T data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            children = new List<TreeNode>();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

will the resulting subclass be forced to use integers when creating `TreeNode`s, and therefore never be able to break the intent I had?

*Disclaimer: yes, I know I'm probably doing plenty of things wrong here.  I'm still learning C#, coming from a mostly Java and Lisp background, with a little bit of plain C.  So suggestions and explanations are welcome.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be forced to use the same type. Look at the declaration again:

```
public class Tree<T>
{
    public class TreeNode
    {
        private T Data;
    }
}
```

So the type of `Data` is determined when you instantiate a specific `Tree`:

```
var tree = new Tree<int>();
```

This way the type of `Data` is declared as `int` and can be no different.

Note that there is no non-generic `TreeNode` class. There is only a `Tree<int>.TreeNode` type:

```
Tree<int> intTree = new Tree<int>(); // add some nodes
Tree<int>.TreeNode intNode = intTree.Nodes[0]; // for example

Tree<string> stringTree = new Tree<int>(); // add some nodes
Tree<string>.TreeNode stringNode = stringTree.Nodes[0]; // for example

// ERROR: this won't compile as the types are incompatible
Tree<string>.TreeNode stringNode2 = intTree.Nodes[0];
```

A `Tree<string>.TreeNode` is a *different* type than `Tree<int>.TreeNode`.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense.  Since `TreeNode` is an inner class, a `TreeNode` can't be created without a _typed_ `Tree<T>`.  So even though the subclass can use it like `TreeNode`, it's actually `Tree<T>.TreeNode` implicitly.

Comment: @KristenHammack Exactly. Inside the `Tree<T>` class you can refer to it as `TreeNode` as the compiler knows what you mean. Outside that scope you would have to specifiy explicitly what _kind of_ `TreeNode` you are referring to (e.g. `Tree<int>.TreeNode`).

Answer (score 0):

The type `T` declared in the outer class may already be used in all its inner declarations, so you can simply remove the `<T>` from the inner class:

```
public class Tree<T>
{
    public TreeNode root;
    //...

    public class TreeNode
    {
        List<TreeNode> children;
        T data;
        public T Data { get { return data; } }

        public TreeNode(T data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            children = new List<TreeNode>();
        }
       //...
    }
}
```